# 'Reviewer stats' on suggested-edits shows an incorrect information

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits, statistics

Path to reproduce the bug:

1. Go to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) queue and select Suggested Edits.
2. Click on the tab [history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history).
3. Look to a post where you either approved or rejected, **and** which the decision was made by 3 to 2 votes no matter the final decision (i.e., approved or rejected).
4. Inside the main box, click in the link named `more`.
5. Look at the reviewer stats of yourself and see if it has the correct count for rejected edits.

Currently, there are more than 100 reviews of suggested edits approved and rejected, but in the scenario described it only shows 6 rejects.

Here are some examples of posts in that situation: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5921765),[b](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5916633),[c](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5877430),[d](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5824236),[e](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5819483),[f](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5923228),[g](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5819479),[h](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5819377),[i](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5819420),[j](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5683024).

Questions:

1. Can you reproduce this bug with your own posts?
2. Is it possible to see on the links above the text `rejected 6 edit suggestions` besides my user name on the reviewer stats?

<sub>This also happens going through the [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144085/andre-silva?tab=activity) tab in the user profile page. I am using Windows 7 and Google Chrome.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been fixed today, as I can no longer reproduce the bug.

**Edit**. According to Shog9:

> There were a few things broken during [yesterday's reshuffling of rejection reasons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) and today they got fixed.

Comment: Official answer is that there were a few things broken during [yesterday's reshuffling of rejection reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) and today they got fixed - including this. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Shog9: Still not right. See my rejection counts in these two suggested edits: [6241884](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6241884) and [6241839](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6241839). I get 2 and 34 (at the moment).

Comment: @NisseEngström, I believe this is another issue. That time the problem was indeed fixed. It was specific for cases where the decision was made by 3 votes against 2 (no matter approved or rejected). The examples you've cited are a little bit different. Maybe you can start a different post.