# Wildly different rejection counts for same user

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits

When I look at old suggested edits, and click on the `(more)` link to view the accept- and reject-counts, I get wildly different rejection counts (on myself) for no apparent reason.

**Examples:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6246790: 3 rejected edits (bogus)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6246656: 47 rejected edits (correct)

At the moment, I can't seem to find a single suggested-edit with 3 straight approvals or 3 straight rejections that have the correct count. It seems to be the ones with mixed votes, or other-than-3 votes that have the correct rejection counts.

Is this a bug or is something else going on?

**Note:**

There is a similar question from a month ago:

- [Suggested edits showing the wrong stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272597/)

But that was posted at a time when there was another similar bug which, according to comments, is believed to be unrelated to my bug report:

- ['Reviewer stats' on suggested-edits shows an incorrect information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273031/)

Comment: FWIW, I just looked at it and the stats are the same. [I think it is a caching issue.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @ChrisBaker: Yes. _Today_, I get 3 almost everywhere and sometimes 0.

Comment: I see a mix of 3 (wrong, I counted as far as four on your profile to verify) and 47. Also looking at the user of your final link, they have a problem, it says 7, and I got to count to eight to verify.

Comment: I get both with 3.

Comment: I see 4 and 51 now. Weird that they both also increased at different rates.

Comment: *puts his money in account merging*

Comment: @Braiam: I've only ever had one account. And I'm far from the only one with strangely low rejection counts.

Comment: I've been seeing the same issue with some frequency, with [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7116346) showing 634 rejections (sounds about right), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7115992), but [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7116173) are both showing 1 rejection (definitely not right).

Comment: @femtoRgon: Not everybody seems to see the same numbers, and the numbers change from time to time, at least when further reviews are made. This issue may be affected by multiple factors: Your actual vote, the resulting consensus, whether you choose "Improve Edit" or "Reject and edit" rather than "Approve" and "Reject". I think there was a thread somewhere about some of these factors, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: I also noticed that after changing my username edit rejections count has been reset to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Incorrect suggested edit review count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243910/13) for more details. This has been fixed earlier this week.

The reason you're seeing two different counts for rejected edit suggestions, seemingly at random, is because the old query was grouping by `ReviewTaskResultTypeId` (with a filter for only `Approve`, `Reject`, and `RejectAndEdit` types), and the code was grabbing the first `Reject` or `RejectAndEdit` grouping and displaying that. So it was displaying either your reject count or your reject-and-edit count, when it should sum the two together.

The new code collects three statistics: the `Approve` count, the total `Reject` and `RejectAndEdit` count, and the `Edit` (Improve edit) count, and displays the three separately.

Comment: Yay. My edit statistics feel whole again.

Comment: "improved 37 edit suggestions" includes Edits made in the review prior to the new system. Some of those were "terrible edit abandoned, but edit the post anyway. One use who hasn't reviewed an edit since April 2013 has over 200 "improve". Just sayin'