# Broken review statistics

Tags: support, bug, review-queues

After I've done a suggested edit review, I get shown the following statistics:

> Lundin has approved 1442 edit suggestions and rejected 5 edit
>   suggestions

I have most certainly rejected far more than that... most likely around as many as I have accepted, give or take. So it would seem that the review statistics are broken, either just for my account or for the whole site.

**EDIT**

The statistics have now magically reappeared:

> Lundin has approved 1443 edit suggestions and rejected 1644 edit
>   suggestions

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277063/wildly-different-rejection-counts-for-same-user