# Apparently I'm a Robo Reviewer now?

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits, review-audits

Not sure what is going on tried clearing my cache but still the Suggested-Edits queue is showing weird stats for me as a reviewer.

**Review Stats from [/suggested-edits/6364986](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6364986)**

[image: Stats are wrong]

**Review Stats from [/suggested-edits/6364858](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6364858)**

[image: Stats look right]

Also just in case people are wondering here is my review stats

[image: Review Stats]

87 + 8 does not equal 201??

Can someone explain what is happening here, is it a bug?

---

### Update

Looks like this has happened before due to;

> **Quote from ['Reviewer stats' on suggested-edits shows an incorrect information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273031/692942)**
>
> [yesterday's reshuffling of rejection reasons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)

Also this seems to be related;

- [Wildly different rejection counts for same user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277063/692942)
- [Suggested edits showing the wrong stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edit-showing-wrong-stats)
- [Incorrect suggested edit review count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243910/213963)

Comment: No repro. I see 87-8 on both

Comment: I thought http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6364986 was an audit!

Comment: @Bart seriously? Something not right then because the second image `87 edits approved 72 edits rejected` is closer to the actual statistic.

Comment: :D Okay, ... then that's weird indeed.

Comment: I can see from your review history you have more than 8 rejects, so something's clearly off.

Comment: Looking at my own stats in the tasks, it claims "Unihedron has approved 592 edit suggestions and rejected 77 edit suggestions". That number is clearly incorrect as I've rejected over a thousand edits.

Comment: Thanks @Flexo I was starting to think I was going mad.

Comment: @Unihedron Not just me then... *phew*

Comment: FYI I think you can view your history at: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history?userId=692942&skipped=true much clearer than in the profile.

Comment: @Flexo Yeah I know, but that is the stat others see and make judgements on or at least I know I do. It's also a quick snapshot of what you have approved and rejected in each queue without having to trawl through the history and count them up.

Comment: The rejection count is completely bogus _most of the time_.

Comment: @NisseEngström Is it?, usually fine for me or I would have been posting this sooner.

Comment: @Lankymart: I don't have any actual statistics, but that's how it appears to me. Perhaps it is different for other users.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Incorrect suggested edit review count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243910/213963), and [Inconsistent count of suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195383/213963) with a number of linked questions there.  This appears to be a known (and old) bug.  Part of that appears to be related to posts that are *deleted* that you had reviewed being used for some displayed numbers.

Comment: Here is another interesting case: [**0 + 0 = 363**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6367910).

Comment: @robinCTS That suggested the problem [had been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307585/692942), but this was posted after that to raise the bug again. I even mention the link to that article in my question.

Comment: Now you're just trying to get me confused, @Lankymart ;-) Isn't  the posted date of that answer *"answered Oct 7 '15 at 13:09"* whilst the posted date of this question *"asked Dec 2 '14 at 11:27"*?

Comment: @robinCTS confused myself

Comment: (No jokes this time.) gunr2171 asked the dupe target [Suggested edits showing the wrong stats](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272597) on  2014-10-01 13:39:08Z. You asked your question (this post, the dupe) [Apparently I'm a Robo Reviewer now?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278251) on 2014-12-02 11:27:00Z. Then you edited in the link to gunr2171's question on 2014-12-02 15:39:44Z. The last comment on your question occurred on 2014-12-03 00:18:02Z and your last edit occurred on 2014-12-06 01:36:00Z.

Comment: **Ten months later** on 2015-10-06 15:01:21Z, Chris Jester-Young [announces](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/267480) that the bug has been fixed and will be deployed soon. The next day on 2015-10-07 13:09:26Z gunr2171 [self-answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307585) to state that the bug-fix has been deployed. I think your original comment *"That suggested the problem had been fixed, but this was posted after that to raise the bug again"* is in error (your question was not posted *after* gunr2171's answer, but 10 months prior to it) as you misread the *year* on the time-stamp of gunr2171's answer.

Comment: (Don't worry. A similar misread of the year in a time-stamp has happened to me as well ;) )