# Better way to get Suggested Edit percent Approved than manually counting?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Using this photo as an example, let us assume there are 213 marked Approved and 20 Rejected.
[image: suggestions]

- Is there an easier way to know the percent (213/233 = 91.4%) other
  than manually counting 20 at a time?
- Can you add an option `?Count=100` to get 100 at a time on the ***All Actions*** view?

Comment: [There is also an SEDE query to reveal this information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297816/where-can-i-find-suggested-edit-review-stats). (Note that the bug that prompted the linked question has [long since been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273072).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. On that same page (activity > all actions > suggestions), click on an individual edit (it will say "approved" or "rejected" or "pending"), then on the reviewer stats button:

   [image: James Risner had 42 edit suggestions approved, and 3 edit suggestions rejected]
2. Add and divide. 42/(42+3) ≈ 93%

Note: For some reason the number shown in your suggestion tab says there are only 42 edits, so there may be 3 on deleted posts.